# Button title doesn't show with annotation

Tags: ios, dictionary, uibutton, mkmapview, mkannotation

Here's my problem. I created a red pin with a button thanks to my viewForAnnotation method.But the button doesn't show. Here my code:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id                 <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {
     //static NSString *defaultPinID = @"identifier";

MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

if ( pinView == nil )
{
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    pinView.enabled = YES;
    pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    [btn setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn;
}
else
{
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
}
pinView.annotation = annotation;

return pinView;
}
```

Can someone help me plz?

Comment: Your question title says "Button _title_ doesn't show...".  Do you mean you don't see the word "test" on your button and instead you see a "i" with a circle around it?  If so, you'll need to set the button's frame with a large enough width that allows the title to be visible to the "i" icon's right side.  If you don't want the "i" icon, use UIButtonTypeCustom instead of UIButtonTypeInfoDark.

Comment: I can't see the word "test". I used UIButtonTypeCustom with btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,140, 100) but it's not working. I tried with the other button types and no results. Either it's not working (no button dispayed) either I can see the "i" icon (all the cases with no title)

Comment: So you get a callout but you don't see a button in it, right?  When you tap on an annotation, does it show the annotation title in a small popup?  Make absolutely sure the map view delegate is set (connect the map view's delegate outlet to the view controller or in code do mapView.delegate = self).  How do you know for sure the viewForAnnotation is getting called?  Put an NSLog or breakpoint in there.

Comment: I get a callout but I don't see the button in it (for some button types I can see the "i" icon). But in all the cases no button title is displayed. The map view delegate is set and the viewForAnnotation is called (thanks to NSLog).

Comment: Try a frame of CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 30) because the default callout is limited to about 32 points in height.  You were trying 100 points so the word "text" was outside the callout's frame.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you added the annotation to you map?
2. Have you set the MKMapView's delegate?
3. Does your viewForAnnotation function get called?